# Recursion for checking an occurrence of a certain digit (no loops only recursion required)

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def helper_number_of_ones(n:int, counter:int)->int:
    if n == 1:
        counter += 1
        return counter
    else:
        if n % 10 == 1:
            counter += 1
        if n // 10 == 1:
            counter += 1
    return helper_number_of_ones(n-1,counter)

def number_of_ones(n: int) -> int:
    count = 0
    return helper_number_of_ones(n,count)
```

My code basically checks for the number of digit one occurrences, throughout all numbers between n and 1, for example n=13 will output 6 for 6 ones occurrences, the only problem it doesn’t work
properly for numbers bigger than 100? Thanks in advance

Comment: Define “it doesn’t work”. Give examples and error messages if any.

Answer (score 1):

Your code takes into consideration two possibilities:

1. The ones digit is 1 (`if n % 10 == 1`)
2. The tens digit is 1 (`if n // 10 == 1`)

This is enough for numbers up to 99, but fails for higher numbers.

I would suggest to break your function into two separate functions: one that counts the number of occurences of 1 in a single number, and another that does that for a range of numbers (using the first one of course).

Answer (score 1):

It is because of how you calculate `counter`

```py
...
        if n % 10 == 1:
            counter += 1
        if n // 10 == 1:
            counter += 1
...
```

For example, if n = 100, it will fail both ifs. You can make a function that calculates the number of 1 in a number recursively.

```py
def num_of_one(number):
    if number == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return ((number % 10) == 1) + num_of_one(number // 10)
```

Then make another function to calculate it over the range.

```py
def range_num_of_one(max_num):
    if max_num == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return num_of_one(max_num) + range_num_of_one(max_num - 1)
```